# String to array based on regex

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I would like to split a string base on regex.

**Expected input:**

```
1. recipe description. 2. second step of the description that takes 30 minutes. 3. third step of the description that contain 20g of flour.
```

Now like to split the string based on the starting number. Is that possible?

**Expected outcome:**

```
[
"recipe description.",
"second step of the description that takes 30 minutes.",
"third step of the description that contain 20g of flour."
]
```

I already tried it with `const steps = text.split(new RegExp("/^d./", "g"));` but its not the expected outcome i would like to have.

Comment: code is looking fro start of a string, letter d, and `.` is any character https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ed.%2Fg and your code will have problems when you reach 10 steps once you fix the problems.

Comment: There's no need to use `new RegExp()` here. You're also not escaping the `.` character, nor are you escaping a \ character for your `\d` input. Just use `/\d\./g` directly. Also, think about using sites like [regex101](http://regex101.com) or [regexr](http://regexr.com) to actually know what you're writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var text = "1. recipe description. 2. second step of the description that takes 30 minutes. 3. third step of the description that contain 20g of flour.";
var steps = text.split(/\s*\d+\.\s*/g).slice(1);
console.log(steps)
```

This splits on a number followed by full stop, possibly with whitespace on either end.  Your current pattern seems to attempt to target a single digit only appearing at the start of the string, and there are other problems as well.

Slight edit: Call `slice(1)` on the array returned from the split, to remove a dummy empty string element resulting from the split on the first number.

Comment: The output of this has the first index being `""`